# Dark mode theme ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am building a web application and would like to give the user the option to toggle the theme from the original one to a Dark Mode one.

I have two different .css files, one for the original theme and one for the dark mode one, but I don't know how to implement such a button.

For now I have the function:

```
function updateStyleSheet(filename) {

        newstylesheet = "Content/" + filename + ".css";
        if ($("#dynamic_css").length == 0) {
            $("head").append("<link>")
            css = $("head").children(":last");
            css.attr({
                id: "dynamic_css",
                rel: "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: newstylesheet
            });
        } else {
            $("#dynamic_css").attr("href", newstylesheet);
        }

    }
```

And I call it using:

```
<input type="button" onclick="updateStyleSheet('bootstrap-SUPERHER')" value="Dark Mode">
```

However, when I go on another page the theme goes back to the original one. How do I make it be constant?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ColbyBoren I have updated the question with my progress.

Comment: You'll have to _persist_ that "selection" on client (e.g. [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), check for existence of that "persisted variable" and obtain it's value, if any, otherwise some "default". This would be global (all your pages), so `_Layout.cshtml` is likely where this goes.